Creating struct/interface for Advent of Code helper in Go
I'm using Advent of Code to learn Go and was looking for tips and feedback on how I'm using Go.   Here's code I came up with for a helper with puzzles that have what I call an Area.   I would call it a Map but trying to create a local variable named map interferes with Go's built in map so I decided on 'Area' for the name.
package aoc

type Area struct {
    Width  int
    Height int
    Data   []byte
}

func (area Area) Get(row, col int) byte {
    return area.GetIndex(row*area.Width + col)
}

func (area Area) GetIndex(index int) byte {
    return area.Data[index]
}

func (area Area) IndexToRowCol(index int) (int, int) {
    row := index / area.Width
    col := index % area.Width
    return row, col
}

func (area Area) RowColToIndex(row, col int) int {
    return row*area.Width + col
}

func (area Area) Inside(row, col int) bool {
    return (row >= 0 && row < area.Height) && (col >= 0 && col < area.Width)
}

func (area Area) InsideIndex(index int) bool {
    return area.Inside(area.IndexToRowCol(index))
}

func (area Area) Clone() *Area {
    newArea := Area{area.Width, area.Height, make([]byte, len(area.Data))}
    copy(newArea.Data, area.Data)
    return &newArea
}

func ParseArea(content string) *Area {
    lines := ParseLines(content) // slice of strings for each line in content
    area := Area{len(lines[0]), len(lines), make([]byte, len(lines[0])*len(lines))}
    for row, line := range lines {
        copy(area.Data[row*area.Width:], []byte(line))
    }
    return &area
}

An example using it is my solution to 2024 day 8 (prior solution without).
Certain things I'm interested in:

Am I creating a new Area correctly?   Should I have NewArea(width, height int) and use that in my ParseArea() function?  Am I using * and & correctly?
I convert between Row and Column and what I call 'Index' in several places.   Row and Column are easier to think about and required for some calculations, but I use 'Index' for things like keys into a map of bools to set a flag for if something exists at that location.   Maybe there's a better way?
I thought about just finding the locations of each line and having slices pointing to sections of the underlying bytes in the content string for optimization so I wouldn't copy any data.   But sometimes I want to clone the slice for instance on Day 5 when I had to try placing blockers and using recursion but didn't want to mess up my original Area.  Having the entire data indexable and copyable as a block seemed like the way to go.
Should I name things differently?

